# What is the input list structure for NaiveBayesClassifier?

Tags: python, csv, nltk, naivebayes

I made a CSV file of tweets bigram and binary label as follows. I want to run the `NaiveBayesClassifier` on it.

```
bigram,label
I love,0
love you,0
I hate,1
hate you,1
...
```

I've read many pages and didn't find the proper answer. I wrote the code below inspired by examples that seems to work, but I don't know how it should be modified to classify my CSV rows (as a list or dictionary inputs).

```
from nltk.classify import NaiveBayesClassifier
import nltk.classify.util

# and why this structure has to have 'True'!
# I'm not sure about this assignment
train_set = [({('hello'): True}, 'positive'), ({('earth'): True}, 'positive')]
test_set = [({('goodbye'): True}, 'negative'), ({('mars'): True}, 'negative')]

classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_set)

accuracy = nltk.classify.util.accuracy(classifier, test_set)
print('Accuracy:', accuracy)
```

Please give me a hand.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load your dataset to a pandas dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df= pd.read_csv('yourcsvfilename.csv')

from sklearn.model_selection  import train_test_split
feature_col = ['bigram']
predicted_class=['label']
X= df[feature_col].values
y= df[predicted_class].values
split_test_size = 0.30  #split your dataset into training set and test set 70%(training set) 30%(test set)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split (X,y, test_size=split_test_size, random_state=  42)

#Training on Naive Bayes Classifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
gnb = GaussianNB()
gnb.fit(X_train, y_train.ravel())

from sklearn import metrics #for accuracy
gnb_train_predict= gnb.predict(X_train)
print("Accuracy= ", metrics.accuracy_score(y_train, gnb_train_predict))

#for test set
gnb_test_predict= gnb.predict(X_test)
print("Accuracy= ", metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, gnb_test_predict))
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer but it comes with an error:
KeyError: "None of [Index(['label'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

Comment: check if there are any whitespaces in the column name "label" by  running df.info()

Comment: I forgot to mention that the accuracy in the code is for your training set. To get you test set ``` gnb_test_predict= gnb.predict(X_test)
print("Accuracy= ", metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, gnb_test_predict))```

Comment: Any other suggestions to edit CSV file structure are welcome :)

Comment: No whitespaces, I removed all spaces after commas: 'bigram, label' --> 'bigram,label'. But still:
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'I love'

Comment: Oh you mean you have both bigram and label in one cell. Split it into two columns.

Comment: No, there are comma-separated. Exactly as what I wrote in the question. If there is no trouble please write your preferred CSV file into the answer.